# How to find a comboxbox having selected user value

Tags: jquery

I do have 5 combobex with same class.

I would like to find among which combobox has selected value 5 in them

my attempt:

```
$(document).ready(function($){
    previous = 0;
    $('.check').focus(function () {
        // Store the current value on focus and on change
        previous = this.value;
    }).change(function() {
        // Do something with the previous value after the change
        //change previous container with value
        newVal = this.value; 
        //alert(previous);
        console.log('Old Val: ' + previous + '- new val:' + newVal);
        $lst = $('.ranking option[value=' + newVal + ']:selected');
        console.log('one ' + $lst.length);

        // Make sure the previous value is updated
        previous = this.value;
    });

});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery make it easy to filter out elements based on their values, names, etc

```js
$('.check').filter(function(){
  return $(this).find('option:selected').val() == 5;
})
```

The function above will return only the select elements that have value 5 selected only.

Here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/N2bya/

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can check my [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KevinIsNowOnline/NQ73T/) complete with all the codes you need.

here is a snippet of the whole code:

```
$('select').change(function (){   //trigger for the change event of the comboboxes

    var selectedIndex = $(this).prop("selectedIndex");
    if(selectedIndex === 4) { //basically the 5th item as it is zero indexed
        alert('you have chosen the fifth item');
    }
});


$('#checker').click(function (){   //for checking of all items with item number 5 selected
   indexChecker(); 
});

var indexChecker = function (){
    var controlList =[];
    $('select').each(function (){
        if($(this).prop("selectedIndex") === 4){
            controlList.push($(this).attr('id'));

        }
    });
    alert('You have selected the fifth element in <select> element with id of : '+ controlList);
};
```